# Get an anemometer to activate a solenoid bolt and as low-tech as possible

Tags: circuit-design

To all you bright  minds out there
I have a project where I would like to stop a large outdoor wooden turntable from moving in moderate to high wind. The idea is to buy an anemometer off eBay that has an output of 0 to 5 volts
Or 4 to 20 mA And has an input voltage requirement of 12 to 24 V.

I would like the output voltage/current to control a circuit with a relay switch that when the wind speed gets up to for example 3 V or 10ma the relay will Kick in and switch on a solenoid Bolt which would stop the turntable from turning. And then when the wind drops, the bolt releases and the turntable is free again. This is for a project I’m doing in the garden. A high wind could destroy, the sculpture if it overpowers the turntable mechanism.
Is it possible to have a variable resistor in the circuit? so I can adjust the sensitivity of the relay kicking in the solenoid bolt. I wanted all this to be very low voltage so it could work off a Solar cell and rechargeable battery.

I went to art school and then did design and I’m learning electronics. So I am a rookie.

Any advice would be most helpful to stop the turntable moving in moderate to high wind

Comment: It might even be possible for the wind to power the solenoid directly.

Comment: @user253751 not really, no.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Are you sure? Why not? (Obviously I mean an anemometer might be able to power the solenoid directly)

Comment: Think about it... gust of wind so now the system has power, but it's already spinning and the solenoid misses the detent, then the gust drops and the solenoid releases, then another gust...  it's just not sensible.  Maybe using it to charge a battery could work, but as described below, a well designed system might just use primary batteries and get several years from them.

Comment: A ball is balanced on a pole and is also tied to a string that goes through a pulley above it. When it's windy, the ball will fall and pull the string, which pulls a locking pin on the turntable. No electricity needed. Must be reset manually.

Comment: perhaps this is an X-Y problem question ... maybe the anemometer is not the best solution ... maybe limiting the rotational speed of the platform, no matter what causes the rotation is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

This will be an extremely challenging project, especially when you add the solar/battery concern.

Honestly you'd be better off just manually locking down the object except when it is in use, and perhaps using electronics to remind the user to do so (annoyance beeper, etc).

If you really want to build a gadget, then while analog solutions using comparators, etc are theoretically *possible* in practice it has been decades since such a solution would be a wise choice.  Instead, a sensible modern solution would use a low power microcontroller.  This would periodically wake up, measure the wind speed, do some time average filtering and make a decision before going back to sleep.  Getting an MCU project to run at lower power is a challenge with many potential pitfalls, but it is something routinely done by careful engineers.

A solenoid is probably not the locking mechanism you want, if you wish to be economical of power.  Instead, you probably want some sort of gearmotor-driven lock or brake, such that it will cost some power to activate it, but zero power while at rest in either locked or unlocked position.  Software will manage running the motor until you detect it has complete the change of position.  You'll need a battery system to save up energy from weak solar input for periodic actuation.   Possibly it will be simpler to just use a primary (disposable) battery solution and not bother with the solar which adds a lot of design complexity and may in unsophisticated usage never pay off the energy cost of its fabrication.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your input. An MCU with a disposable battery is the route I am going to take.

Comment: Have fun with the project!  You'll need to pay extreme care to make sure you aren't leaking power somewhere while trying to be asleep - signals asserted against pulling resistors, regulator quiescent currents (best not to use a regulator, ATmegas have a nice wide input range), H-bridge quiescent currents...

Answer (score 0):

For low-power operation, you're going to want a braking mechanism that is bi-stable — does not require power to remain in either the braked or unbraked state. Instead of a solenoid, think in terms of a screw mechanism driven by a small motor. And instead of a "bolt", it might be better to have a friction pad against either the rim or the underside of your turntable.

And an anemometer with an analog output is probably overkill. The simplest anemometers consist of a reed switch and a small magnet on the spinning part. A microcontroller can measure the interval between contact closures to determine the wind speed.

So, combine these ideas together, and you have a workable system that can operate on the power budget provided by a small solar panel and a battery.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your input. A screw mechanism/friction pad and a simpler anemometer will be the route I am going to take.

Answer (score 0):

For a purely mechanical solution, use a centrifugal governor as used by old steam engines to apply a friction brake as the speed increases. See [image]

Image from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_governor

Comment: Thank you very much for exploring this idea with such great suggestions. How they say one thing leads to another. The centrifugal governor is a work of art in itself. I think guests will be marveling at this feat of engineering instead of admiring my sculpture! I might have to box it! Food for thought indeed.